# gcc/ld can't find ldpdk, even with -L and ldconfig for dpdk-burst-replay

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, ld

I'm trying to `make` the project [`dpdk-burst-replay`](https://doc.dpdk.org/burst-replay/quick-start-guide.html), but the make process failed with the following error:

```
gcc -g -O2 -W -Wall -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/dpdk -march=native -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -W -Wall -DNDEBUG -O2  -L/usr/local/lib -pthread -lnuma -lm -ldl -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,--start-group -ldpdk -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o dpdk-replay dpdk_replay-main.o dpdk_replay-cpus.o dpdk_replay-dpdk.o dpdk_replay-pcap.o dpdk_replay-utils.o

/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/ld: cannot find -ldpdk

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [dpdk-replay] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/dpdk-burst-replay/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/dpdk-burst-replay'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So the particular problem here is `ld: cannot find -ldpdk`, and you can see from the gcc statement that there is : two declarations for directories : `-I/usr/include/dpdk` and `-L/usr/local/lib`.

But I have the `/usr/include/dpdk` folder as a symbolic link as following:

```
[user@server ~]$ ls -l /usr/include/ | grep dpdk
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root     88 Jul 27 07:30 dpdk -> /home/user/project/_build/lib/src_ext/dpdk/src/dpdk/x86_64-native-linux-gcc/include/
```

And inside `/usr/local/lib` there is the archive (i.e. static library) : `libdpdk.a'

```
[user@server ~]$ ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep dpdk
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 83 Jul 27 08:13 dpdk -> /home/user/project/_build/lib/src_ext/dpdk/src/dpdk/x86_64-native-linux-gcc/lib

[user@server ~]$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/dpdk/ | grep dpdk
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user    2791 Jul 27 05:55 libdpdk.a
```

So, basically `libdpdk.a` exists in `/usr/local/lib/dpdk/` (which is a symbolik link if that matters).

Also I have edited `/etc/ld.so.conf` to add those pathes as following:

```
[user@server ~]$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/home/user/project/_build/lib/src_ext/dpdk/src/dpdk/x86_64-native-linux-gcc/lib
/home/user/project/_build/lib/src_ext/dpdk/src/dpdk/x86_64-native-linux-gcc/include
```

Also I've checked the following:

```
[user@server ~]$ sudo ld -verbose -L/usr/lib/dpdk -ldpdk | grep dpdk.a
attempt to open /usr/lib/dpdk/libdpdk.a succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/dpdk/libdpdk.a
opened script file /usr/lib/dpdk/libdpdk.a
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

But still `cannot find -ldpdk`

EDIT1: Important note: the makefile is autogenerated by some tools, and Iit is not recommended to modify it.

EDIT2: I have modified the gcc flag `-L/usr/local/lib` to be `-L/usr/local/lib/dpdk` and it **worked**!(Thanks to @secret squirrel for the idea of modifying the gcc command for test).
=> So basically, the problem is that `-L/path/to/lib` is not finding the `dpdk` library, maybe because it is a symbolic link?

By the way, I just tried both versions of gcc 4.8.5, and gcc 8.3.1.

I'm working on x86_64 machine, using Linux Centos7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could try putting the -L/usr/local/lib at the end of the gcc command (ie after ..dpdk_replay-pcap.o dpdk_replay-utils.o)

Comment: Actually I can't modify the the gcc command, as it is in a Makefile that is autogenerated, but eventhough, I think the start/end group tags `--start-group -ldpdk -Wl,--end-group` are meant to omit this ordering issue.

Comment: Any way, I just copied the gcc command and added `-L/usr/local/lib`, but still the same error `ld: cannot find -ldpdk`

Comment: It is looking for dynamic version, not static, libdpdk.so. Do you have it? Should be under /usr/lib64 . In centos it is contained in dpdk-devel package I think.

Comment: Your library is in the `/usr/local/lib/dpdk` directory. Why on god's green earth would anyone expect the linker to find it in `-L/usr/local/lib/`?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., so the `-L/PATH/TO/LIBs` will not start a recursive search inside it?

Comment: "will not start a recursive search inside it" Of course not. Where did you get this idea?

Comment: I think you may write this as an answer.